# ng-model value with multi-select disappears on refresh when only one value selected

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following Angular code:

```
        <select
                class="form-control chosen-select ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-scope localytics-chosen ng-valid ng-valid-required"
                chosen
                multiple
                data-placeholder="Select Field"
                ng-options="value for (key, value) in plugin.allCollections"
                ng-model="plugin.item.collections"
                id="{{plugin.context}}collections">
        </select>
```

Where `plugin.allCollections` is an object of the form

```
{
  3938757: "some collection",
  3932012: "some other collection"
}
```

In which the keys are numerical, and I only want to save the text values to `plugin.item.collections`.

It seems to be working insofar as when I save, I properly receive the string values as an array in the backend.

However, if I only select one collection, and then save it, it seems the single collection remains bound to the object (i.e. if I console log `plugin.item.collections` I will see `["some collection"]` as expected) -- but it disappears from the UI on refresh. BUT if I have more than one selected/saved, they won't disappear on refresh.

What's causing this difference in behavior, and how can I stop the value from disappearing when only one is selected?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up figuring this out eventually. The problem was that for some reason, when there was only one element, the Javascript Object was actually an array. With more than one, it turned into an object of the form `{0: "collection one", 1: "collection two"}` etc., as opposed to `["collection one"]`

Anyway, the solution was to convert it into an Object if it was an Array:

```
if (Array.isArray(collections)) {
  collections = { ...collections } // convert to Object to render in ng-model
}
```

Hope this helps on the off-chance anyone else stumbles across this with a similar issue!